# How to extract table content from CSV file after been converted from PDF with Python?

Tags: python, csv, pdf

I have a PDF that contains many tables. )I converted this PDF to CSV online, to extract the needed data more easily.)

The CSV rows are composed of many columns, but each table contains only 3 columns, so it is hard to know which column refers to a cell.

I also should mention that one cell can be composed of more than one line and column.
[An example of a table](https://gfi1-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/mansour_trabelsi_gfi-tunisie_com/EbD7BEXeg65Mi7ZVt0eqFQUByJ4FzvuFBLm-ugh52hLhdQ?e=WanFJS).

So is there any solution to extract these cells?

```
import csv
import re
class PDF_EXTRACTOR:
    FILE_NAME=None
    Ttableau=None
    NUMBER_OF_PAGES=None
    def __init__(self,fn):
        self.FILE_NAME=fn
        self.Ttableau=0
        self.NUMBER_OF_PAGES=0
    def EXTRACT_CELLULE(self):
        csv.register_dialect('mydialect',delimiter =',',skipinitialspace=True)
        print(csv.list_dialects())
        with open(self.FILE_NAME,'r',encoding='utf8',errors='ignore') as csvFile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='mydialect')
            for index, row in enumerate(reader):
                print(row)
```

I expected an output like this:

```
["Region 1","Region 2", "Region3]
["8,3-9","AUXILIAIRES DE LA MÉTÉOROLOGIE 5.54A 5.54B 5.54C",""]
["70-72","70-90","70-72"]
["RADIONAVIGATION 5.60","FIXE","MARITIME 5.60"]
```

But instead I got this:

```
['7 450-8 100', 'FIXE', '', '', '', '']
['', 'MOBILE sauf mobile aéronautique (R)', '', '', '', '']
['', '5.144', '', '', '', '']
['8 100-8 195', 'FIXE', '', '', '', '']
['', 'MOBILE MARITIME', '', '', '', '']
['8 195-8 815', 'MOBILE MARITIME', '5.109', '5.11', '5.132', '5.145']
['', '5.111', '', '', '', '']
['8 815-8 965', 'MOBILE AÉRONAUTIQUE (R)', '', '', '', '']
['8 965-9 040', 'MOBILE AÉRONAUTIQUE (OR)', '', '', '', '']
['9 040-9 305', '9 040-9 400', '', '', '', '9 040-9 305']
['FIXE', 'FIXE', '', '', '', 'FIXE']
['9 305-9 355', '', '', '', '', '9 305-9 355']
['FIXE', '', '', '', '', 'FIXE']
['Radiolocalisation 5.145A', '', '', '', '', 'Radiolocalisation 5.145A']
['5.145B', '', '', '', '', '']
['9 355-9 400', '', '', '', '', '9 355-9 400']
```

Comment: Do you expect a serie of lists as output ?

Comment: In the CSV rows, there are many empty cells (['9 355-9 400', '', '', '', '', '9 355-9 400']), so i can't determine if this two columns, are C1 and C2, or C2 C3, but if the CSV row was like that (['9 355-9 400', '', '9 355-9 400']), so it will be easy to know that this about C1 and C3.